Generate Fail Fast scenario using Multiple Thread in JAVA
I need a scenario to generate ConcurrentModificationException using multi-thread. Please have a look at the below code, here I am getting IllegalThreadStateException.
Not sure why this is happening and also what could be the correct example for my scenario.
public class MultiThreadFailMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l  = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            l.add(1);
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            l.add(1);
        });
        l.forEach(v -> {
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        });
        System.out.println("\n---------------");
        l.forEach(System.out::print);
    }
}


The IllegalThreadStateException is because each thread is started multiple times. I’m unsure about what you’re trying to achieve. If you’re trying to trigger a ConcurrentModificationException, CopyOnWriteArrayList never throw it as far as I know.  It is designed for safe concurrent use.

For starters,
        l.forEach(v -> {
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        });

should be
t1.start();
t2.start();

Otherwise you're trying to start the thread more than once.
Second, CopyOnWriteArrayList is specifically a kind of list that won't cause a ConcurrentModificationException.
Third, most ConcurrentModificationExceptions don't actually have anything to do with multiple threads.  See, for example, this question.
